# How to pass a file with space in the name to command FC?

Tags: windows, batch-file, arguments, parameter-expansion

I have a diff script that wraps the command `FC` so that I just have to drop two files on it:

```
FC /L /N "%1" "%2" > diff.out.txt 2> diff.err.txt
```

It works fine, but if one of the files has spaces in the name...
For example, my file paths being `C:\Users\joH1\Desktop\file_with a_space.txt` and `C:\Users\joH1\Desktop\file_2.txt`, I get the error (sorry for localization):

```
FC : commutateur non valide

FC : impossible d'ouvrir C:\USERS\JOH1\DESKTOP\FILE_WITH - Ce fichier ou dossier n'existe pas
```

So, the file name is split as two separate arguments, *even though the paths are quoted*.

To find out where this comes from, I added lines to my script:

```
echo %1
echo %2
FC /L /N "%1" "%2" > diff.out.txt 2> diff.err.txt
pause
```

I get correct output for the `echo`s (though args are unquoted!):

```
"C:\Users\joH1\Desktop\file_with a_space.txt"
"C:\Users\joH1\Desktop\file_2.txt"
```

I even tried with `dir` to make sure `echo` was not merging back the split args, and I got a correct result (file was recognized and listed => name not split).

So; I guess `FC` is to blame here.

Is there a way of telling it *not* to split a file name? (like quotes are supposed to?)
I'd like a way that is compatible with drag & drop, and that is not *Rename your files without spaces*, if possible...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it's not `fc` causing the issue; you are dragging-and-dropping files onto your script, so Windows/`cmd` may put quotes as needed (so when white-spaces or special characters are present), which you are doubling when using `"%1"`; using `"%~1"` is the best solution as shown by an answer, as the `~` removes potential quotes before quoting the arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FC /L /N "%~1" "%~2" > diff.out.txt 2> diff.err.txt
```

*should* read your files. I'm assuming your parameters are merely double-quoted and that they don't contain <kbd>`</kbd> as posted.

Comment: @joH1, As an expansion of this answer; you're doubling up the doublequotes, which means that the `FC` command is seeing an empty parameter, `""` before it sees `C:\Users\joH1\Desktop\file_with a_space.txt"" ""C:\Users\joH1\Desktop\file_2.txt""`

Comment: Yeah, the backticks were a failed copy-paste operation. I can't check this out now (back home on 'nux) so I'll do it tommorow (UTC+0200 here) at the office. Thanks already, tho!

Comment: @Compo even on bash it works: `var="\"var\"; echo $var` echoes `"var"`, so I ended up with... double-double-quotes... quad-quotes?

Comment: @joH1, we're not on bash so I'm not sure how your comment is relevant, unless you're sending the arguments to the Windows batch file from the bash shell. That said your command above has an opening doublequote and two escaped inner ones, that is unbalanced isn't it?

Comment: @Compo it's only an example to show that whatever  the system, embedded double quotes end up in the variable's expansion, and it appeared to me obvious when I translated it to Bash (which I'm more used to)

Comment: @Compo and the missing quote is just a typo, I actually meant `var="\"var\""`